# ISP Config tells me to delete index.html from my web directory / And it doesn't exist

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ispconfig

I recently copied a wordpress directory from a subdomain to another different ,

From *`< name >.lalala.com`  , to `< second-name >.lalala.com`* ....

As well as I got a Wordpress installed and working.

Inside both subdomains, in *`< root >/web`* subfolder I got WP installed.

But, in the new/second subdomain where I pasted WP content, I get this message...

[image]

So I look for the `index.html`, and doesn't exists in web folder and any folder inside.

I check `.htaccess` and don't have fault about it.

So I don't know where to continue here... Why this?

Some help? What can be?

[image]

Here I post my web folder with files as any other Wordpress folder. What's wrong?

**I Can access database, I got data copied too... As well as wp-options for url...**

Comment: copying a wordpress website may be tricky. i suggest using a migrate website plugin for this

Comment: Is it possible that you're logged into your FTP as the wrong subdomain? Perhaps you could try create a test file in your `web` directory, and try access it from your browser, to ensure that you've got the correct FTP connection.